# Clickable divs not working with javascript

Tags: javascript

I want my divs to run a function when clicking them but they dont seem to want to do anything. I am new to javascript and the function I am trying to run is just a test. Please check it out and tell me what needs to be changed and anything wrong with the rest of the code.

Code: https://github.com/Duskope/rockpaperscissors

```js
const weapons = document.querySelectorAll('weapons')
const result = document.getElementById('result')
let userChoice

weapons.forEach(weapon => weapon.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    userChoice = e.target.id
    result.innerHTML = userChoice
}))
```

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: blackjack;
    src: url(/rockpaperscissors/font/blackjack/blackjack.otf);
}

body {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-family: blackjack;
    background-color: #3B3D3C;
    color: #26B198;
    height: 100vh;
}
.maingrid {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}
#title {
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
    font-size: 40px;
}
#desc{
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 30px;
}
#weaponsgrid {
    justify-content: center;
}
.weaponimg {
    height: 240px;
    margin: 20px;
    border: 4px;
    border-color: #27C39A;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.weapons {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 350px;
}
.weaponlabel {
    align-self: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin: 0;
}
.weapons:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
#footer {
    justify-content:center;
    align-content: flex-end;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-top: 470px;
}
#resultDisplay {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src = "index.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/rockpaperscissors/styles.css"
</head>
<body>
    <div class="maingrid" id ="title">
        <h1 class="mainhead">Rock Paper Scissors</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="maingrid" id="desc">
        <h2>Choose your weapon</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="maingrid" id="weaponsgrid">
     <div class="weapons" id="rock">
            <p class="weaponlabel">Rock</p><img src="/rockpaperscissors/images/bbaeb9dc-f31f-498b-8183-2073e1361f49-1656364575448.jpg" alt="Rock" class="weaponimg">
        </div>
        <div class="weapons" id="paper">
            <p class="weaponlabel">Paper</p><img src="/rockpaperscissors/images/paper.png" alt="Paper" class="weaponimg">
        </div>
       <div class="weapons" id="scissors">
            <p class="weaponlabel">Scissors</p><img src="images/scissors.jpeg" alt="Scissors" class="weaponimg">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="maingrid" id="resultDisplay">
        <span class="result"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="maingrid" id="footer">from Daddy Duskope</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should post your code snippes here. Anyways the problem is in your sellector at `const weapons = document.querySelectorAll('weapons')`. Check this out: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: please put some code to debug your problem

Comment: he has a link, but nobody has accepted the edit in queue yet.

Comment: can you resolve the edit in quere @KunalTanwar? you have enough rep

Comment: Unfortunately you need to have `2k` reputation to approve an edit. 

Comment: i made a working version: https://replit.com/@Hermanboxcar5/randomtests#index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by using `querySelectorAll()`, you are selecting all the html elements that are `<weapons></weapons>` and such. instead of selecting using the tag name, set them all to the same class, e.g

```
<div class='weapons'>...</div>
```

and doing `getElementsByClassName('weapons')` instead. Hope it helps!

EDIT:

here is a revised version:

```
const result = document.getElementById('resultDisplay')
let userChoice;

document.getElementById('rock').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    userChoice = 'rock'
    result.innerHTML = userChoice
})
document.getElementById('paper').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    userChoice = 'paper'
    result.innerHTML = userChoice
})
document.getElementById('scissors').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    userChoice = 'scissors'
    result.innerHTML = userChoice
})
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/rockpaperscissors/styles.css"
</head>
<body>
    <div class="maingrid" id ="title">
        <h1 class="mainhead">Rock Paper Scissors</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="maingrid" id="desc">
        <h2>Choose your weapon</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="maingrid" id="weaponsgrid">
     <div class="weapons" id="rock">
            <p class="weaponlabel">Rock</p><img src="/rockpaperscissors/images/bbaeb9dc-f31f-498b-8183-2073e1361f49-1656364575448.jpg" alt="Rock" class="weaponimg">
        </div>
        <div class="weapons" id="paper">
            <p class="weaponlabel">Paper</p><img src="/rockpaperscissors/images/paper.png" alt="Paper" class="weaponimg">
        </div>
       <div class="weapons" id="scissors">
            <p class="weaponlabel">Scissors</p><img src="images/scissors.jpeg" alt="Scissors" class="weaponimg">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="maingrid" id="resultDisplay">
        <span class="result"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="maingrid" id="footer">from Daddy Duskope</div>
  <script src = "index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

master can be found at https://replit.com/@Hermanboxcar5/randomtests#index.html

Comment: I appreciate the response, when I do this I get an error that weapons.forEach is not a function. It only seems to work with queryselector

Comment: then do `querySelectorAll('.weapons')`

Comment: the `.` implies that it is a class

Comment: Also, place your `<script>` tag after your html, it lowers your site loading time (and just good practice)

Comment: ... and uh also you don't really have anything with id set to 'result'

Comment: try reading js tutorials on https://www.w3schools.com

Comment: After some debugging work, I found that your event listener works, but `e.target.id` returns undefined for some reason. Try setting the listeners one by one, since you only have 3 divs

Comment: here is a version that works:

Comment: https://replit.com/@Hermanboxcar5/randomtests#script.js

Comment: view result in https://randomtests.hermanboxcar5.repl.co/

Comment: i tried a little modified version of that code, and moving my script tag to the bottom of the body got the whole thing woking. thx bro

Answer (score 1):

```js
const weapons = document.querySelectorAll('.weapons') // .weapons as weapons is class therefor .
const result = document.querySelector('.result') // changed to querySelector
let userChoice

weapons.forEach(weapon => weapon.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  userChoice = e.target.id // added id to img as img is being is e.target
  console.log(userChoice)
  console.log(result)
  result.textContent = userChoice // setting textContent and not innerHtml
}))
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: blackjack;
  src: url(/rockpaperscissors/font/blackjack/blackjack.otf);
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: blackjack;
  background-color: #3B3D3C;
  color: #26B198;
  height: 100vh;
}

.maingrid {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

#title {
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-size: 40px;
}

#desc {
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#weaponsgrid {
  justify-content: center;
}

.weaponimg {
  height: 240px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 4px;
  border-color: #27C39A;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.weapons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 350px;
}

.weaponlabel {
  align-self: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 0;
}

.weapons:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

#footer {
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: flex-end;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-top: 470px;
}

#resultDisplay {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/rockpaperscissors/styles.css" </head>

  <body>
    <div class="maingrid" id="title">
      <h1 class="mainhead">Rock Paper Scissors</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="maingrid" id="desc">
      <h2>Choose your weapon</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="maingrid" id="weaponsgrid">
      <div class="weapons" id="rock">
        <p class="weaponlabel">Rock</p><img id="Rock" src="/rockpaperscissors/images/bbaeb9dc-f31f-498b-8183-2073e1361f49-1656364575448.jpg" alt="Rock" class="weaponimg">
      </div>
      <div class="weapons" id="paper">
        <p class="weaponlabel">Paper</p><img id="Paper" src="/rockpaperscissors/images/paper.png" alt="Paper" class="weaponimg">
      </div>
      <div class="weapons" id="scissors">
        <p class="weaponlabel">Scissors</p><img id="Scissor" src="images/scissors.jpeg" alt="Scissors" class="weaponimg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="maingrid" id="resultDisplay">
      <span class="result"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="maingrid" id="footer">from Daddy Duskope</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Changes are:

```js
const weapons = document.querySelectorAll('.weapons') // .weapons as weapons is class therefor .
const result = document.querySelector('.result') // changed to querySelector

userChoice = e.target.id // added id to img as img is being is e.target
result.textContent = userChoice // setting textContent and not innerHtml
```

`id` added to every `img` tag